# Browser cache, Last-Modified header

Tags: header, http-headers, browser

Let's assume there are two URLs:

```
http://example.com/myaccount?user=12345
http://example.com/myaccount?user=34567
```

As far as I understand the browser will cache them separately and will not use the Last-Modified header from the first request to revalidate the second.

***Is it possible to force the browser to use the Last-Modified header in this case?***

***Could you please explain why does it work this way?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in certain situations the web server will ignore the query string. You can try for instance on a out-of-the-box Apache server do `curl -I http://example.com/styles.css | grep Last-Modified` and then run the same command for `http://example.com/styles.css?v=2`. Assuming the file exists, you'll probably get the same Last-Modified timestamp.

It might be the browsers (my guess is that they do that) who consider the `?v=2` as a different file or a file with an updated content. Also, I think that most Content Delivery Networks will be configured that way which allows to serve a fresh copy of a file if its query string differs.

It's an interesting question anyway. I'll read up on it more. I hope that somebody might explain this more closely here.